# How to stop the window scrolling to the top of the page on my navbar toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

Whenever I click the toggle menu button on my navbar, the window scrolls to the top of the page. Is there any way to get the menu to appear over wherever the page currently is?

I have a feeling it's linked to the parts of the navbar which I had to hide due to overflow.

codepen: https://codepen.io/Ribeye/pen/BajOoeb

Thank you!

Script

```
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
    var $nav = $('nav');
    
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```

CSS

```
.imgServices {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.l-left {
  float: left;
}

.l-right {
  float: right;
}

.end {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
  transform: translateY(300px);
  transition: opacity, -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: opacity, transform 1s;
  transition: opacity, transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.header-top {
  background: white;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  z-index: 12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

h1 a {
  color: red;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: "arial black";
  font-size: 35px;
}

.first-letter {
  color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "arial black";
  font-size: 45px;
}

.toggle-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.toggle-menu i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 16px;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 24px;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 32px;
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  background: transparent;
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}

nav {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .25);
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open-menu~nav {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 80px 0;
  z-index: 15;
  height: calc(90vh - 70px);
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  flex: 1;
}

nav li a {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background .3s;
}

nav li a {
  background: #ff4b4b;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background: #ADD8E6;
}


/*These 3 sections add the drop dwon menus in the headers*/

ul li ul.services-dropdown {
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover ul.services-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}

ul li ul.services-dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
}

h2 a {
  padding: 8 8 8 8px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
  background: white;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #212121;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .edit-name {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*Removes the tel and email when window is narrow */

@media (max-width: 1230px) {
  .narrow-hide {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*Edits the nav bar when window is narrow */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav li {
    margin-top: 1px;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .scroll-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    html {
      font-size: 50%;
    }
    .open-menu~nav {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    nav li a {
      padding: 3px;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="header-top clearfix">
    <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="hide">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com ">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.google.com "> Services</a>
                 <ul class="services-dropdown ">
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com ">whats</a>   </li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com ">Stuff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com ">Things</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.google.com ">News & Events</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.google.com ">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.google.com ">Data Protection</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.google.com ">Data Protection</a>
          </li>                               
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <body>
<img class="imgServices" src="https://lindhill.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/light-blue-block.png" alt="blue"></body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of `href="#"` present on the anchor tag. Add `event.preventDefault();` inside the onclick function, and it will be fine

```js
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');
 
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```

```css
.imgServices {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.l-left {
    float: left;
}
.l-right {
    float: right;
}
.end {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
            transform: translateY(300px);
    transition: opacity, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity, transform 1s;
    transition: opacity, transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.header-top {
    background: white;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    z-index: 12;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    
}
h1 a {
    color: red;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-family: "arial black";
    font-size: 35px;
}
.first-letter {
    color: red;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "arial black";
    font-size: 45px;
}
.toggle-menu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
.toggle-menu i {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.toggle-menu i:nth-child(1) {
    top: 16px;
}
.toggle-menu i:nth-child(2) {
    top: 24px;
}
.toggle-menu i:nth-child(3) {
    top: 32px;
}
.open-menu i:nth-child(1) {
    top: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
            transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.open-menu i:nth-child(2) {
    background: transparent;
}
.open-menu i:nth-child(3) {
    top: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
nav {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .25);
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.open-menu ~ nav {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 80px 0;
    z-index: 15;
    height: calc(90vh - 70px);
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
}
nav li {
    flex: 1;
}
nav li a {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background .3s;
}
nav li a {
    background: #ff4b4b;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
nav li a:hover {
    background: #ADD8E6;
}

/*These 3 sections add the drop dwon menus in the headers*/

ul li ul.services-dropdown{ 
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover ul.services-dropdown{
    display: inline-block;  /* Display the dropdown */
     }
     
ul li ul.services-dropdown li{
    display: block;
 }

section { 
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
    
}

h2 a{
    padding: 8 8 8 8px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
}
#fp-nav ul li a span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
    background: white;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}
#fp-nav ul li a.active span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span, 
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #212121;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {

  .edit-name{
    display: none;
  }
  
}

/*Removes the tel and email when window is narrow */

@media (max-width: 1230px) {

  .narrow-hide{
    display: none;
    
  }
  
}

/*Edits the nav bar when window is narrow */
 
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
 
    nav li {
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
  
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
  .scroll-icon {
    display: none;

}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  
  .open-menu ~ nav {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
 
    nav li a {
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="header-top clearfix">
    

    <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </div>
 
  <nav class="hide">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>
        <a href=""https://www.google.com">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"> Services</a>
             <ul class="services-dropdown">
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">whats</a>   </li>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Things</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">News & Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Contact Us</a>
      </li>                                 
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
                                        
<body>
                                                    <img class="imgServices" src="https://lindhill.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/light-blue-block.png" alt="blue">
                                             </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just eliminate de href="#" from the 3rd line in the html.
So this:

```
<a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</a>
```

should look like this:

```
<a class="l-right toggle-menu">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</a>
```

For an explanation, what is happening here is that the navigation is being activated to "#" which what it does is to look up the id given (here none was given [ex. href="#myId"]) and move the window's viewport to that element. Right now since there is no element found it just sends you to the top of the document

Answer (score 0):

You used in your hamburger menu `<a>` tag with `href="#"` and that is the mistake, I changed the `<a>` tag with a `<div>` tag and in your JS code I changed the find with 'div';

```js
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');
 
$header_top.find('div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```

```css
.imgServices {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.l-left {
    float: left;
}
.l-right {
    float: right;
}
.end {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
            transform: translateY(300px);
    transition: opacity, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity, transform 1s;
    transition: opacity, transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.header-top {
    background: white;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    z-index: 12;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    
}
h1 a {
    color: red;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-family: "arial black";
    font-size: 35px;
}
.first-letter {
    color: red;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "arial black";
    font-size: 45px;
}
.toggle-menu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
.toggle-menu i {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.toggle-menu i:nth-child(1) {
    top: 16px;
}
.toggle-menu i:nth-child(2) {
    top: 24px;
}
.toggle-menu i:nth-child(3) {
    top: 32px;
}
.open-menu i:nth-child(1) {
    top: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
            transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.open-menu i:nth-child(2) {
    background: transparent;
}
.open-menu i:nth-child(3) {
    top: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
nav {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .25);
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.open-menu ~ nav {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 80px 0;
    z-index: 15;
    height: calc(90vh - 70px);
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
}

nav li a {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background .3s;
}
nav li a {
    background: #ff4b4b;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
nav li a:hover {
    background: #ADD8E6;
}

/*These 3 sections add the drop dwon menus in the headers*/

ul li ul.services-dropdown{ 
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover ul.services-dropdown{
    display: inline-block;  /* Display the dropdown */
     }
     
ul li ul.services-dropdown li{
    display: block;
 }

section { 
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
    
}

h2 a{
    padding: 8 8 8 8px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
}
#fp-nav ul li a span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
    background: white;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}
#fp-nav ul li a.active span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span, 
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span, 
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #212121;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {

  .edit-name{
    display: none;
  }
  
}

/*Removes the tel and email when window is narrow */

@media (max-width: 1230px) {

  .narrow-hide{
    display: none;
    
  }
  
}

/*Edits the nav bar when window is narrow */
 
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
 
    nav li {
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
  
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
  .scroll-icon {
    display: none;

}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  
  .open-menu ~ nav {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
 
    nav li a {
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-top clearfix">
    

    <div class="l-right toggle-menu">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <nav class="hide">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>
        <a href=""https://www.google.com">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"> Services</a>
             <ul class="services-dropdown">
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">whats</a>   </li>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Things</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">News & Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Contact Us</a>
      </li>                                 
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
                                        
<body>
   <img class="imgServices" src="https://lindhill.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/light-blue-block.png" alt="blue">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag. the `href` attribute is set to `#`, that is why the window goes to the top.

```
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```